# Which direction is "up" according to judaism

Tags: geography, direction

Does Judaism have an opinion as to which direction is "up"? So do we just follow the general consensus, for example we say north is up and south is down? Or do we have other directions?

Comment: In the Torah north is left and south is right.

Comment: So east is up? Is there a source for that? Or just that we pray that way?

Comment: [ארץ ישראל גבוהה מכל הארצות](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.234.7#:~:text=%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%AA,%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA)

Comment: Whenever people travel to the capital city of a country they say they are "going up to the city" regardless of the direction in which they travel.  It is an expression of respect for the status of the city.

Comment: Not specifically Jewish, but medieval [T&O maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_and_O_map) were traditionally *oriented* (note the word) with East at the top, in contrast to Ptolemy's earlier map

Comment: I think "up" is "up" and is not a cardinal direction (that association of north to up is just a 'conspiracy of cartographers'). Consider the halachic opinions about how to shake a lulav אבל המנהג פעיה''ק ירושלים ת''ו כמו שכתב רבינו האר''י, להקיף דרום צפון מזרח מעלה מטה ומערב.

Comment: Can you give a halachic reason why we would need to know which way is up?

Comment: I'm just curious as to whether we have a similar expression that up is north and if it agrees with the goyish one

Comment: I don't have a source on hand, but as @DoubleAA pointed out - Mizrach (East) orients toward "up" in Kabbalistic literature, with North being left and South being right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, whether up is the right word, but east is considered to be forward. (Up for me is an elevation from the ground.) See for example [Bemidbar 34:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.34.15), where to denote east of the Jordan the word קדמה (forward) is used. Similarly, the word אחרון (backward) is used to describe the Mediterranean Sea, which is backwards if we face eastwards ([Devarim 11:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.24)).