# How am I to understand this passage "13: He made them ride upon the high places of the earth"

Tags: deuteronomy, parshat-devarim

In Parshat Ha'azinu, 3rd Portion (Devarim (Deuteronomy) 32:13-32:18)
It is written
"13 He made them ride upon the high places of the earth"
But if you create a simple search in google you'll see that the highest places in the world are:

Bhutan (10,671 feet) Bhutan has the highest elevation of any country in the world. ...
Nepal (10,712 feet) Mount Everest is 8,848 meters high. ...
Tajikistan (10,453 feet) ...
Kyrgyzstan (9,806 feet) ...
Lesotho (7,090 feet) ...
Andorra (6,549 feet) ...
Afghanistan (6,181 feet) ...
Chile (6,138 feet)

So if that is the case, then what else can the passage above mean.
If you look at the targum and sifrei
it says as follows:
He made them ride upon the high places of the earth: This entire verse is to be understood as rendered by the Targum [i.e., referring to the Land of Israel].

יַרְכִּבֵהוּ על במתי אָרֶץ: כָּל הַמִּקְרָא כְּתַרְגּוּמוֹ:
He made them ride [upon the high places]: [referring to] the Land of Israel, because it is higher than all other countries. — [Sifrei 32:13]

Does anyone here have any more insight into this?
Because if it means that it is the highest place on earth physically, clearly it isn't.
but spiritually, yes for sure.
but the issue is: sifrei and targum do not write this.

Comment: The earth is a sphere; the highest place depends on your vantage point.

Comment: Gave you an upvote to push your reputation to over 1000. Congrats and cheers :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I reject this explanation. Either it's the highest point of the earth or it's not. 
Spiritually, Israel Is MOST DEFINITELY the most High Holiest place on earth.
 
I believe there are other meforshim out there that specifically say that verse in parshat haazinu is referring to Benei Yisrael riding on the highest parts of the earth spiritually.

יגיַרְכִּבֵ֨הוּ֙ עַל־בָּ֣מֳתֵי (כתיב על־במותי) אָ֔רֶץ וַיֹּאכַ֖ל תְּנוּבֹ֣ת שָׂדָ֑י וַיֵּֽנִקֵ֤הוּ דְבַשׁ֙ מִסֶּ֔לַע וְשֶׁ֖מֶן מֵֽחַלְמִ֥ישׁ צֽוּר:

and NOT physically, because why would riding high physically even be applicable?

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen the highest point on earth depends on how you define high.

> Mount Everest's peak is the highest altitude above mean sea level at 29,029 feet [8,848 meters].
> Mount Chimborazo's peak is the furthest point on Earth from Earth's center; and the closest to space. The summit is over 6,800 feet [2,072 meters] farther from Earth's center than Mount Everest's summit.
> Mauna Kea is the tallest mountain from base to peak at more than 33,500 feet [10,210 meters].

The [Chasam sofer](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer,_Yoreh_De%27ah_234.7) on this topic, acknowledges the fact that there seem to be higher points on earth than Israel, but dismisses this logic and redefines the meaning of height as follows:

> וקרא כתיב וקמת ועלית אל המקום ופירש"י מכאן שגבוה ב"המק מכל א"י ובחי תורה שלי בארתי שלכאורה יפלא לאמור מכאן שגבוה מה לשון מכאן נחזי אנן והוא דבר הנראה לעין ונמדד בקנה ועוד שהאמת אינו כן והוא מבואר לבקי קצת במפת העולם ועוד רש"י פי' כן בפסוק כטל חרמון שיורד על הררי ציון שחרמון גבוה והנה העולם עגול ככדור ובדבר כדורי לא שייך גבוה ונמוך ובכל מקום שעומד שם רואה שמים שעל ראשו גבוהי' וסמוך לאופק נמוכים ככיפה והבא ממקום האופק נדמה לו כעולה מתחתית עומק בור ולא שייך גבוה ונמוך אך נחזי אנן אם יהיה לפנינו כדור עגול ואנו מכירים בו נקודה א' שממנה שתיית הכדור ההוא ונתרחב משם והתפשט ונעשה עגול כמות שהוא וכל הפיות אליו פונים וממנו יונקים יניקת חיותם והוא המרכז האמתי של הכדור ואז בלי ספק מכל צד שפונים אליו נקרא עלייה לא עלייה במעלה וגדולה המקום לבד אלא עלייה ממש כמי שעומד במקומו ורואה האופק שסביביו ירוד ועמוק וכן בהיפך כיון שכל הפיות אליו פונים א"כ הכל עמוק ממנו ועולים אליו כיון שהעולם כדורית

Since the world is a sphere there is no highest or lowest point. The highest point would be the sky. Wherever one stands on earth seems to him to be the highest point, for when he looks to the horizon it curves downward, making everything approaching him seem to come up toward him. Rather, there's only a central point. A place where everyone turns to.

> והיינו דאמרי' בספרי הנ"ל וקמת ועלית וקשה לו ומאי פסקא הלא אפשר שהזקן ממרא וב"ד יושבים בהר חרמון שמשם יורדים לירושלים ולא עולים אלא מכאן שב"המק גבוה מכל א"י שהוא משתיתו של עולם מתחלת יצירה והוא מרכז ונקודה האמצעי שבכדור וא"כ כל הבאים לשם עולים ולא יורדים כנלע"ד מ"מ א"א לומר כן על מקום אחר או על צפת ויעקב אע"ה אמר זה שער השמים ואין ב' שערים.

This central point is the beit hamikdash and Israel, which is the foundation of the world. It is the central, and by our new definition highest, point because from there is the gateway to heaven (and there aren't two gateways), and provides for the rest of the world. So following the logic previously stated, Israel is physically, and spiritually the highest point on earth.

Comment: Hey [I know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136694/which-direction-is-up-according-to-judaism#comment455208_136694) that one ;)

Comment: Yup. ThanQ good sir for teaching me well.

Comment: @Shababnik amazing source and very interesting way of proving that Israel is _physically_ the highest point

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank my newfound rebbie shmosel

Comment: Rabbi Dovid Brown in "Mysteries of Creation" has a chapter called "Summit of the World" and he asks and answers OP's question, and arrives at the same conclusions as you. If you don't mind (and I have time) may I edit your answer and include some of his sources and arguments?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Be my guest. (While you're at it can you fix my grammar?) ;)